# Conditions for being harmonic in a region $R$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove that the function $G=\ln|f(z)|$ is harmonic in a region $R$ if $f(z)$ is analytic in $R$ and also $f(z)\cdot f'(z)$ does not equal zero in $R$.

My difficulty here is that the expression for the Laplacian of $G$ is very big and ugly, and I know that I have to apply the Cauchy-Riemann Equations somewhere , but it is not clear to me how and where.
Also the condition of the multiplication of the complex function with its derivative not being zero looks rather mysterious . Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Saying that $f(z)f'(z) \neq 0$ just means that neither $f(z)$ nor $f'(z)$ are zero.

Comment: However, zeros of the derivative wouldn't hurt at all here.

Comment: @MikeMiller : I'd have said neither $f(z)$ nor $f'(z)$ _is_ zero.  I wonder if using "are" rather than "is" is on its way toward being considered standard usage?

Answer (score 1):

Trigger warning: If the phrase "multiple-valued function" causes you pain, then stop reading here.

Suppose we define
$$
\operatorname{Log} z = \log |z| + i\arg z \tag 1
$$
where $\operatorname{Log}$ is "multiple-valued" because $\arg$ is multiple-valued.  The different branches of $\operatorname{Log}$ differ by a constant and so all have the same derivative, which is $1/z$.  If you like, just restrict attention to some region within which $\operatorname{Log}$ is single-valued.  Then it's holomorphic, and thus harmonic.  If $f$ is holomorphic then the chain rule tells us $\operatorname{Log}\circ f$ is holomorphic.

So suppose you can prove

- $(1)$ is holomorphic (maybe by showing that it's locally an inverse of $\exp$?), and
- The real part of a holomorphic function is harmonic.

Then you've got it.  If your question is how to prove these two points, then I would need to add more, but otherwise maybe I can hope this answers your question.

Comment: But what lovely pain! You're first line buys my vote!  ***Endorsed!!!***

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response ,but I still do not get it